# Trouble with placing form content in JSP page

Tags: html, jsp

I'm having diffucelty with placing a form that is used to browse text. I have a big chunck of text that suppose to appear in the middle of the page, and two indentical forms that suppose to appear above and below the text. the trouble is that both form appear above the text
I've tried to use footer tag but it didn't work. here is the jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
<head>
<title>Unity Zohar</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8\">
<link type="text/CSS" href="ErrorStyle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/CSS" href="TextStyle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

    <h4>Zohar Portion Name: ${bean.parashaName}, paragraphs: ${bean.paragNum}, #of paragraphs: ${max}</h4>

    <form action="ReadZohar" method="get">
        <input type = "hidden" id = "command" name ="command" value = "read"/>
        <input type = "hidden" id = "block" name ="block" value = "1"/><br>
        פרשה: <select id = "parasha" name="parasha" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <c:forEach  var = "pbean" items = "${list}">
        <option value="${pbean.number}"${pbean.number == lastPick ? 'selected' : ''}>${pbean.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="previous" onclick="previous()">
        <input type="submit" value="forward">
    </form>


    ${bean.text}



    <form action="ReadZohar" method="get">
        <input type = "hidden" id = "command" name ="command" value = "read"/>
        <input type = "hidden" id = "block" name ="block" value = "1"/><br>
        פרשה: <select id = "parasha" name="parasha" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <c:forEach  var = "pbean" items = "${list}">
        <option value="${pbean.number}"${pbean.number == lastPick ? 'selected' : ''}>${pbean.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="previous" onclick="previous()">
        <input type="submit" value="forward">
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function previous(){
    document.getElementById("block").value = "-1";
}
</script>
</body>
<div class="errMsg">${error}</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Encapsulate the 2 forms & the text in individual `div` tags with `display:block;width:100%`

Comment: do you mean <div style="display:block;width:100%">? it doesn't work

Comment: Create single form and manage it through table / div.

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/Gzy8J/). I've added a border to show that the 3 sections appear one below the other.

Comment: @srvikram13 I really appriciate your effort but it still dosen't work. maybe it has someting to do with the fact that ${bean.text} actually creats a table?

Comment: Just edit my fiddle and paste the final markup of the 2 forms and `${bean.text}` output in individual divs & check the output.

Comment: @srvikram13  Done. still not working. take a look http://jsfiddle.net/Gzy8J/1/

Comment: @Alaychem inspect the hierarchy of the 3 divs in your fiddle. The div containing the `table` is nested within the second form div.

Comment: @srvikram13 you mean that I forgot to close the table... post your comment as answer so I will approve it. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: HTML Markup]

You are missing the closing `</table>` tag in your code that is causing the table container to  merge into the second form container.

Hope this helps.

Comment: well the code you show is smewhat inaccurate since the seconed div closes before the thrid starts but thanks anyhow

Comment: @Alaychem FYI that's not the code. That's how the markup was being generated by your code when the `<table>` tag was not closed.
In any case, glad I could help.